# creating accumulator function (python)

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create an accumulator function that is called repeatedly with single numeric argument and accumulate its argument into a sum. Each time it is called, it returns the currently accumulated sum. An example is given below.

```
A=make_accumulator()
A(10) -> 10
A(20) -> 30
A(-15) -> 15
```

Comment: You instantiate a class and then treat it as a function?

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyAccumulator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0
    def add(self, number): 
        self.sum += number
        return self.sum

A = MyAccumulator().add
print(A(10))      # => 10
print(A(20))      # => 30
print(A(-15))     # => 15
```

something like this ?